# Sum of N terms of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Perhaps this is a silly question but how can I simplify this to find the sum of $N$ terms?

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2n - 1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

I know how to find the sum of cubes and squares etc but how with the denominator like that?
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

The questions in the book have all involved finding things like:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N {(3n^3+n^2+n)}$$

This is the only one with the cubes and squares in the denominator

Comment: Do you mean, how to find the sum of the expression as $n$ varies from, say, $1$ to $N$?

Comment: Yes, how to find the sum to n terms. I have the answer:n(3n+1)/ 4(n+1)(n+2)

Comment: I have the solution too but the path I found is more than likely too complex.

Comment: If you want the less elegant and most stupid solution (mine !), just tell me.

Comment: Thanks for all the help though I'm still not sure how to proceed to get the answer in the book

Answer (score 11):

Checking if there is a pair of constants $(A,B)$ such that 
$$\frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=A\cdot\color{red}{\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}}+B\cdot\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$$
gives us $(A,B)=(5/2,-1/2)$.

Hence, since we can have

$$\frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{5}{2}\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)}-\frac 12\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)},$$
we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{5}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac{5}{2}\left\{\left(\frac 12-\frac 13\right)+\left(\frac 13-\frac 14\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac 1N-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}\right)\right\}$$$$-\frac 12\left\{\left(\frac 11-\frac 12\right)+\left(\frac 12-\frac 13\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N}\right)+\left(\frac 1N-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)\right\}$$
$$=\frac 52\left(\frac 12-\frac{1}{N+2}\right)-\frac 12\left(\frac 11-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)=\frac{N(3N+1)}{4(N+1)(N+2)}.$$

Comment: This is very elegant ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks:)

Comment: Thanks, though I am still not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @user160232: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: Fantastic! Cheers. I was assuming it was solved by summing the powers of natural numbers, using the formulas this is an elegant solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @user160232: Glad to help you! You are welcome.

Comment: @mathlove - nice solution. a small tweak may be required: setting $N=1$ gives $\dfrac 16$ under the summation (only one term) but the solution gives $\dfrac 12$.

Comment: @hypergeometric: Oh, thank you for pointing it out. I edited it.

Comment: @mathlove - you're welcome... that was very fast!

Comment: This process of splitting the fraction is typically called partial fractions

Comment: .. and the method of telescoping series was used too.

Answer (score 2):

Split this into two parts, each with a simple numerator, which is more convenient for converting to partial fractions.

[image]

The second last line is probably more useful if taking limits as $N\to\infty$ is required.

Check:

Put $N=1$.

LHS = $\dfrac 1{1\cdot  2\cdot 3}=\dfrac 16$

RHS =$\dfrac {1\cdot 4}{4\cdot 2\cdot 3}=\dfrac 16$

Looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}-\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac{3}{4}-\dfrac{4N+3}{2N^2+6N+4}$

Comment: I think I am missing some steps. Could you elaborate ? Thank you.

Comment: nice approach, but more elaboration would help. a small tweak to the solution may be required: setting $N=1$ gives $\dfrac 16$ under the summation (only one term) but the solution gives $0$.

Comment: @hypergeometric: Gee, thanks man. Was using $N$ instead of $N+1$ in that rightmost fraction...

Comment: @barakmanos - you're welcome :) the denominator can be factorised as well.

Comment: @hypergeometric: Yes, of course, but I did the opposite - changed $N$ to $N+1$ and then simplified the expression $2(N+1)(N+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:$$\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac{1}{(n+1)}-\dfrac{1}{(n+2)}$$ and 
$$\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac{1}{2n(n+1)}-\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)(n+2)}$$